# Why Does My PHP Login Script Not Work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I making an Employee Management System and I have stuck at a point where the Super Admin needs to be logged in to check/alter the details of the employees.

The Super Admin is just a single person which will do everything. So I have manually inserted the details of the super admin into the database.

Here's the code and the page is called as superadmin.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Employee Management System</title>
    <link href="../styles/style-index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="styles/style-superAdmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once("../php_includes/pageTop-template.php") ?>
        <div id="pageContentforSuperAdmin">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="form-superAdmin" align="center">
                    <h3>Please Login Super Admin</h3>           
                    <form id="superAdminForm" method="post" action="superadmin.php">
                        <input type="email" name="email" required class="txtInput" placeholder="Email..." autocomplete="off"/>
                        <br />
                        <input type="password" name="password" required class="txtInput" placeholder="Password..."/>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" id="submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php include_once("../php_includes/pageBottom-template.php") ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    include_once("../php_includes/db-connect.php");

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);

        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //echo $password;
        $hash_ver = password_verify($password, $hash);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$hash."'";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if ($rows["email"] == $email && $rows["password"] == $hash) {
            header("Location: admin-index.php");
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect Credentials';
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Now the Problem is that, I am just getting the output as Incorrect Credentials and I don't know the reason why is it so ? For the password, I have used the newly introduced password_hash for hashing it. I have copied and pasted the hash code directly in the database table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try checking query using `mysqli_query($con, $sql)or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: Might be error in your sql syntax due to wrong column name

Comment: So what is the query? Try executing it in php my admin. Maybe you will see what is going wrong. Compare the password in the database with the password being sent. I bet they are different.

Comment: @dipersh Parmar, I have done as you said, but the same output of Incorrect Credentials

Comment: header("Location: admin-index.php");die;

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius, I dont know how to execute it with phpmyadmin as I am new to PHP and MySQL. Please guide me, if you can..

Comment: You said you manually inserted the admin credentials into the database. Thought you would use phpMyAdmin. Check it your way then. Same strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from anything else, I'd suggest you try by replacing your `if` with this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    header("Location: admin-index.php");
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect Credentials';
}
```

As you're already selecting from the database where the username and password match.

Comment: dude, getting the same output of incorrect credentials, when tried as said by you..

Comment: All I can suggest is that you double check your query external to PHP (eg. in the mysql console) and see what you get back.  The fact that you're still getting "Invalid Credentials" means that your query is not returning any rows.  Compare `$hash` with the password stored in the db, check that the field is big enough to store the whole hash too.

Answer (score 0):

`if ($rows["email"] == $email && $rows["password"] == $hash) {`

should be changed to check if there is a record found or not for `$query`.

like:

`if(mysql_fetch_array($query) !== false) {`

Comment: Dude, whatever i type in the textbox, it sends me to the admin-index.php page. What should i do ??